# Is there a way to know what type constraint was passed to a generic typescript function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For example, let's say I have the following function where I test to see if a chess square is controlled on the diagonal. Now what I want is a generic function that works for both the bishop and the queen.

```
static controlsDiagonal<Type extends Bishop | Queen >(board: (Piece | null)[][], x: number, Colour: ColourEnum): boolean{
    const rankMultipliers = [1, -1, 1, -1];
    const fileMultipliers = [1, -1, -1, 1];
    const coordinates = new Coordinates(x);

    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      let offset = 1;
      let fromRank = offset * rankMultipliers[i] + coordinates.rank;
      let fromFile = offset * fileMultipliers[i] + coordinates.file;

      while(fromRank < 8 && fromRank > -1 && fromFile < 8 && fromFile > -1) {
        const piece = board[fromRank][fromFile];

        if(piece !== null){
          console.log("isBishop",piece instanceof Bishop, typeof piece);
          console.log("isQueen", piece instanceof Queen, typeof piece);
          
          /****I want to check piece is an instance of the type that I passed in 
               Now InstanceOf Type doesn't work here ****/
          if(piece instanceof Type && piece?.getColour() === Colour)
            return true;
          break;
          }

        fromRank = ++offset * rankMultipliers[i] + coordinates.rank;
        fromFile = offset * fileMultipliers[i] + coordinates.file;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

For usage I would want to call:

```
return Bishop.controlsDiagonal<Bishop>(board, x, Colour);
return Bishop.controlsDiagonal<Queen>(board, x, Colour);
```

The main reason I need to do it this way is because my queen inherits from my Rook, and since you can only have one superclass I need a different way to "share this function with the queen". The alternative that I am thinking is injecting the function via inversion of control pattern, but I think that may be a tad overkill.

I feel like I should be able to get the instance of the generic type that I passed in, I'm just not certain how to do it.

Comment: _"get the instance of the generic type"_ - those two things are happening at **entirely different times**. TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, the generic type (along with type information in general) is erased and no longer exists at runtime when an actual instance is passed in.

Comment: In your exmaple `Type` should be related to one of arguments. Consider this example https://tsplay.dev/NrGXom . In this example generic argument `Type` is now part of `board` argument. Also, `instanceof Type` is not allowed. Please provide reproducible minimum example with link to TS playground. It will increase your chances to gen a meaningful answer

Comment: thanks guys; @jonSharpe read that on the ms faq
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

however i feel as if i have the right idea; it's just the execution i am lacking on

Answer (score 0):

This is doable, but it's not really a TypeScript issue, as the comments have pointed out.  The problem is that by the time *Javascript* is running your `instanceOf` logic, all the types have been erased so it can't tell what type was passed as a *type* parameter.  Javascript has no concept of a type parameter.

But you can do what (I think) you want, by passing in a class as an argument ( for a real parameter in the function, not a type parameter) and making use of the fact that classes are both objects in Javascript and types in Typescript.  The latter isn't really necessary, but it will make your typing simple.

Here's a simplified example that strips out some of the parts of your code that aren't (again, I think) relevant to your question:

```js
class DiagonalController {
  static controlsDiagonal(somePiece:Piece, pieceExample: typeof DiagonalController ){
    if(somePiece instanceof pieceExample) {
      console.log("I am this type") 
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("I am not this type")
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `pieceExample: typeof DiagonalController` parameter.  That's really the key: it will take as a type a class rather than the instantiation of a class.  (Technically, it's a class constructor function but you can write it as just `ClassName`, which is nice.). That's pretty close to your concept of passing in a type as a type parameter, except you are working Javascript, not Typescript, so the runtime can use it.

After that you just extend this base class as you want and everything works:

```js
class Bishop extends DiagonalController {
  static controlsDiagonal(somePiece:Piece){
    super.controlsDiagonal(somePiece, Bishop)
  }
}

class Queen extends DiagonalController {
  static controlsDiagonal(somePiece:Piece){
    super.controlsDiagonal(somePiece, Queen)
  }

}

class Rook {

}

type Piece = Bishop | Queen | Rook

const piece1 = new Bishop()
const piece2 = new Queen()
const piece3 = new Rook()

Bishop.controlsDiagonal(piece1) // This recognizes it's the right type
Bishop.controlsDiagonal(piece2) // These two recognize they aren't
Bishop.controlsDiagonal(piece3)
```

[Playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=32&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCWYDmB7AdmEBhdAXATiiCAKb7QDeAsAFDTQS5i7zDTB6EgQLLqYAKCCgC2JAArwSwEgC5J0kgBpoABykyAogA8wI1aVnRcAT1UkUAMziJUGbJyKlyASmp160eJaGiJGki80RjA0GSs1AJ09AxIXSlpPTw5gohIAOhAUJAEAIgBJaD1jAAt4GFNzXPjEzwBfWvoSbhJGhI8klOFSTOy8wuK0FFxS8uMzEmq2ho8ZmdBIGAAhcpKUVWgSbVwSNAATGF47TBw0AicydvoQljYU8%204j-hBfMQUZeQC3NogAV3N8Ol7lweLZnq9-IoVCsIGtVC5anNaLQFlBoABFX4kXabba7A42Pj2U4PZxXBhMW7sRyPMH2CHvOSM74dBj-MhAmmgomCYRvAIqTHYtAI2bImgzFHgNEAJRQKAA1u1aJKaJVAozoABeaAwuHQAA%20GKxOKNcsV4q6I3UigAjNroGgSAB3XWrdYCUVWyKKABMDqdrqFu09KPQjB9MgAzAGXdBzQrQzRaHr1pyziCnvSbTJbaLU6p0w9uccXjmSL78%207C8CiCXweWo6LaMG0EXM3TBOW8y2TW3a7SeWWApXe8L23Ws12Ak3xXPkzQgA)

EDIT: I noticed your question says that Queen is a subclass of Bishop.  That will introduce a little more complications because `somePiece instanceof Bishop` will be true for Queens as well.  I don't think it's fundamental to your question; that's just the nature of inheritance.  But it's also not fatal to what you are trying to do.  [Here's a playground that handles that.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCWYDmB7AdmEBhdAXATiiCAKb7QDeAsAFDTQS5i7zDTB6EgQLLqYAKCCgC2JAArwSwEgC5J0kgBpoABykyAogA8wI1aVnRcAT1UkUAMziJUGbJyKlyASmp160eJaGiJGki80RjA0GSs1AJ09AxIXSlpPTw5gohIAOhAUJAEAIgBJaD1jAAt4GFNzXPjEzwBfWvoSbhJGhI8klOFSTOy8wuK0FFxS8uMzEmq2ho8ZmdBIGAAhcpKUVWgSbVwSNAATGF47TBw0AicydvoQljYU8%204j-hBfMQUZeQCVdUVo-UNxuYIisIGsNgBeaAgsFuNreV7%20RRBEJhCzWACKAFcSLt4u4kvQumlejkCkURNAhiNcGUKhMph1oHVNi0rgSnvZTg9nOl7lweLZngj3spIr9dP84tNanNaLQFlBoFicWhNttdgcoat1mybqx2I5HoL7MKAp9FLDGRyToaeXyiAK%20CbhG8vkrsbiZXKaDN5eBFQAlFAoADW7VovpolUCIugkOhOoAPu6VdBk0HQ96uiMfjIAIxxykkADuWtB6wELnl6EYYpkACZC2gSyndpXq8EcwEAMxNlsZkPtmi0BOqXmGx3HF65kh5qs0Ufjs7863TgL1%20eL%201Gp2CGfd%20e0ZW7JcPSdCmdzo8etCnlfGvfr%20fH2-b88m-eH4ff71AA)